# Hibernate Validator - OR Condition

Tags: hibernate, validation

Can I put two annotations in Hibernate (in OR)?

This is my first annotation:

```
@Size.List({
    @Size(min = 16),
    @Size(max = 16)
})
private String test;
```

And i want to put the @Null annotation.

Can i make this two annotation in OR?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine the annotations in an OR. However, you can create an Custom validator for checking null and size with min = 16, max = 16. You can refer to this [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints) to create Custome validator.